# Is $ f \colon (1, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R} , f(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x} $ uniformly continuous?

Tags: uniform-continuity

Is $$ f \colon (1, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R} ,
 f(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x} $$ uniformly continuous? I think it could be but can't prove it. Would appreciate the help.
Edit: I'm looking for an answer in which mean value theorem and boundedness of the derivative isn't used.
So, I'm left with the definition and Lipschitz

Comment: You are asking different questions in title and main body

Comment: sorry I fixed it now

Comment: What is $f$ here, Be specific!

Comment: yes but I'm looking at $ (1, +\infty)$ not $\mathbb{R}$ so it's not the same question?

Comment: Note that $f$ has bounded derivative. The result follows from mean value theorem.

Comment: Don't confuse with the title in this link!

Comment: Use continuity of sin in $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ and $y$ be different points in $(1,+\infty)$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists a point $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that

$$
f(x)-f(y)=\cos(\frac{1}{z})(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y})=\cos(\frac{1}{z})(\frac{y-x}{xy})
$$
Then
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|
$$
So $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz and, in particular, uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

$f^{\prime}(x)= (-1/ x^2)(\cos (1/x))$, which is bounded. So, given function is uniformly continuous.